# PostgreSQL difficulty extracting field from jsonb column

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

Using PostgreSQL 9.5.5
Given the below example jsonb data in a column:

```
{
 "item_id": "123456",
 "action_information_1": [ {"value": "259", "action_type": "read"} ],
 "action_information_2": [ {"value": "93",  "action_type": "read"} ],
 "action_information_3": [ {"value": "53",  "action_type": "read"} ],
 "action_information_4": [ {"value": "35",  "action_type": "read"} ]
}
```

I'm having difficulty programmatically extracting the 'value' from 'action_information_1' which would be 259.

It seems the syntax is slightly different from other examples I've seen, the above has preceding ' " ' in front of the ' [ '.

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: Your example is an invalid JSON document. You need to use `"` around keys and values not `'` and the array `[...]` must not be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: please have a look at http://www.json.org/

Comment: `col->'action_information_1'->0->>'value'` , if you need array index parametrized `jsonb_extract_path(col->'action_information_1',?)->>'value'`

Comment: it's interesting, when I run the original text through a JSON validator, it comes back 'valid'.    {
        "item_id": "123456",
    "action_information_1": "[{'value': '259', 'action_type': 'read'}]",
    "action_information_2": "[{'value': '93', 'action_type': 'read'}]",
    "action_information_3": "[{'value': '53', 'action_type': 'read'}]",
    "action_information_4": "[{'value': '35', 'action_type': 'read'}]"
}

Comment: And this seems to be the big barrier to using in it's original form.

Answer (score 2):

If you fix the syntax errors in the JSON document the following works:

```
with test_data (doc) as (
  values (
   '{
     "item_id": "123456",
     "action_information_1": [{"value": "259", "action_type": "read"}],
     "action_information_2": [{"value": "93", "action_type": "read"}],
     "action_information_3": [{"value": "53", "action_type": "read"}],
     "action_information_4": [{"value": "35", "action_type": "read"}]
    }'::json
  )
)
select doc -> 'action_information_1' -> 0 ->> 'value'
from test_data
```

`doc -> 'action_information_1'` gets the array for that key, the `-> 0` returns the first array element and `->> 'value'` then gets the value that is associated with the key `value`

Alternatively this can be written a bit shorter using:

```
select doc #> '{action_information_1,0}' ->> 'value'
from test_data
```